# SoapUI Groovy script - multiple calls storing values in variable?

Tags: json, groovy, automated-tests, soapui, ready-api

I can't figure this out if its even possible to do in soapUI. Couldn't find much about groovy script here.

I'm using Flickr API, specificaly methods:
[flickr.photos.search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.htm)
As parameters I pass my **user_id** to get all my photos in response.
Let's say I can display only **500 photos per page** --> there is total of **51 pages**.

Is it possible to write some groovy script to:

1. loop through the response, get each photoId and store it in some list or array
2. call the same request, just with **"page": 2** this time
3. repeat step 1 and 2 until photoId is extracted from all 51 pages

Is this possible, will I have the array/list accessible for a different request call?
Or do I need to write the value to some txt file and then when I want to use the values, use the file as data source?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you might be asking three different questions here, so I'll try to narrow that down. Is your main question 1. "can I reuse SoapUI request objects?", 2. "does groovy allow me to add new elements to a single list or array object over time?", or 3. "can I use the results of one SoapUI request to make a different request?"

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.) My main question would be the number 2, then 1. Don't know how to make the groovy script working at all.

Comment: Ok. I think the thing to do is to add some code to the question - show us how you would try to add things to the array. If there are are any error messages, paste the stacktrace in there too.

Comment: Hi, I'd look at data source and data sink in SoapUI.  The above is definitely achievable in SoapUI.  Because of the nature of capturing 1 id from each iteration, I would use Data sink to store these photo ids and then you'd have them as a source for a follow-up test.

Comment: SoapUI the paid version has steps to do this out of the box. The free version, you will have to use a Groovy script to loop through your data. Google search turns up several options.